# A criterion for a $G$-variety to be isomorphic to $G/H$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field *of characteristic* 0.
Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group over $k$.
Let $H\subset G$ be an algebraic $k$-subgroup.
Let $Y$ be an algebraic variety over $k$
and let $y_0\in Y(k)$ be a $k$-point.
Let
$$\theta\colon G\times_k Y\to Y$$
be an action of $G$ on $Y$.
I need a criterion to check whether $Y$ is isomorphic (as a pointed $G$-variety) to $G/H$.

Consider the induced action of $G(k)$ on $Y(k)$ and assume that
(1) $G(k)$ acts on $Y(k)$ transitively, and (2) the stabilizer of $y_0$ in $G(k)$ is $H(k)$.

> **Question 1.** Does if follow that $Y$ is canonically isomorphic, as a pointed $G$-variety, to $G/H$ ?

By definition (see Section 5.5 of Springer's book "Linear Algebraic Groups, 2nd ed.)
a quotient of $G$ by $H$ is a $G$-variety $X$  with a $k$-point $x_0$ having stabilizer $H$
with the following universal property:

> (Q)  For any $G$-variety $Z$ over $k$ with a $k$-point $z_0$ having stabilizer *containing $H$*,
>   there exists a unique $G$-morphism $\nu\colon X\to Z$ sending $x_0$ to $z_0$.

It follows immediately from the universal property that if $(X', x'_0)$ is another such $G$-variety,
then there exists a unique $G$-isomorphism $X\to X'$ sending $x_0$ to $x'_0$.

If $G$ is a linear algebraic group over $k$ and $H$ any  $k$-subgroup, then there exists a quotient of $G$ by $H$,
see Theorem 5.5.5 of Springer's book.

This quotient $X$ is denoted by $G/H$. If $g\in G(k)$, then the $k$-point $g\cdot x_0$ is denoted $gH$.

I am trying to answer my Question 1. Let $X=G/H$. Using the universal property, we obtain a $G$-morphism
$$\nu\colon X\to Y$$
taking $x_0$ to $y_0$, and one can check easily that $\nu$ is bijective of $k$-points.
Note that both $X$ and $Y$ are nonsingular and, by assumption, ${\rm char}\,k=0$.

> **Question 2.** Does it follow that $\nu$ an isomorphism of varieties?

Comment: Once you know flatness of the morphism $\theta_{y_0}:G\to Y$, $g\mapsto \theta(g,y_0)$, you can use faithfully flat descent to construct the isomorphism with $G/H$.  By generic flatness, there is a maximal, dense, open subscheme $U$ of $Y$ over which $\theta_{y_0}$ is flat.  The closed complement is a proper, $G$-invariant, closed subset of $Y$.  Since $Y$ is $G$-homogeneous, this proper subset is the empty set, i.e., $\theta_{y_0}$ is flat.

Comment: . . . The fiber product $G\times_Y G$ is isomorphic to $H\times G$ via the conjugation morphism.  So now you can construct the isomorphism between the datum $(\text{pr}_1,\text{pr}_2:G\times_Y G \to G)$ and the datum $(m,\text{pr}_2:H\times G \to G)$ and apply faithfully flat descent for morphisms to get isomorphisms of $Y$ and $G/H$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you for prompt comment! However, is the answer to Question 1 "yes" and to Question 2 "yes" as well?

Comment: @JasonStarr: Could you please write an *answer*?

Comment: @JasonStarr: In my paper on 3 pages I use this criterion 3 times, and I don't want to check the universal property every time.

Comment: @JasonStarr: If you could write an answer, I will just refer to it in my paper.

Comment: Isn't this Lemma 6.2 of Borel ("Let $\pi : V \to W$ be a surjective open separable morphism of irreducible varieties, and assume $W$ is normal.  Then $\pi$ is a quotient morphism"), with $\pi$ taken to be $\theta(\cdot, y_0)$ as in @JasonStarr's answer?

Comment: (I mean not to replace @JasonStarr's answer, but to give you something to cite.)

Comment: This lemma also seems to be the second part of Springer's Theorem 5.5.5 that you quote ("In fact, if $X$ and $x$ are as in 5.5.4 then $(X, x)$ is such a quotient").

Comment: @LSpice: Exactly, Springer's Theorem 5.5.5 is what I need. I did not read it carefully!

Comment: @LSpice: This is what for one needs MO!